# How to add background-size in css based on image size?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, background-size

I am working on a project where the user will be able to select or upload an image and it will be displayed inside of these circles. The images are dynamically being added as background-images. The problem comes in when I am trying to set the background-size. If the image is larger than the circles, I would like it to have a background-size cover, so it scales down. If the image is smaller than the circle, I don't want it to scale up or anything so setting no background size achieves this effect.

Any ideas on how I could achieve this?

The main html looks like this:

```
<div class="image-boundary">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="image-boundary-photo img-responsive" style="background-image: url('https://www.fillmurray.com/g/100/100');" alt="">
        </div>
    /div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.module-list-home .content .image-boundary-photo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

Here is the codepen of my example. http://codepen.io/johnsonjpj/pen/zKyGZp?editors=1100
The third image should have a background-size: cover; because it is bigger while the others should stay the way they are.

Comment: Is `background-size: contain` what you want?

Comment: @Blazemonger No, I want it to cover if the image is big enough. and stay it's original size if its smaller than the container.

Comment: Instead of a background image, you might use a positioned element with max-width: 100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$('.img-responsive').each(function(key, el) {
    var img = new Image;
    img.src = $(el).css('background-image').match(/^url\("?(.+?)"?\)$/)[1];
    if ($(el).width() <= img.width || $(el).height() <= img.height)
        $(el).css('background-size', 'cover');
})
```

here is a [working example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xEmwyN)

Comment: Awesome! I'll try it in my actual file and let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 2):

You might get some mileage out of the `background-size` setting "`contain`".

I've added it inline to your pen, for a view, here: http://codepen.io/cam5/pen/vXvNOq?editors=1100

It upsizes when they are too small, so might not be entirely what you're after. But querying image's size is very likely going to involve some javascript.  This is a CSS-only approach.

```
<div class="image-boundary-photo img-responsive" 
     style="background-image: url('https://www.fillmurray.com/g/100/100');
     background-size: contain;" alt="It's Bill Murray.">
</div>
```

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size#Values):

> #### contain
>
> A keyword that scales the image as large as possible and maintains image aspect ratio (image doesn't get squished). Image is letterboxed within the container. When the image and container have different dimensions, the empty areas (either top/bottom of left/right) are filled with the background-color.  The image is automatically centered unless over-ridden by another property such as background-position.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at this. I'm fine with some sort of javascript but I don't want the images to scale up. Maybe some sort of check that sees if the image is bigger than the container, and then sets the background-size to cover it is?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting the property `background-size: contain;` in the `.module-list-home .content .image-boundary-photo` class?

To solve the problem of small images also getting too large using `background-size: contain;` use the size as in percentage. e.g.

set the property `background-size:60%;` in the `.module-list-home .content .image-boundary-photo` class instead of contain and i think your problem will be solved.

Hope this helps.

[Edit]

Also wrote solution with jquery dynamically checking image size and adjusting. 
Here is the jquery solution: http://codepen.io/Nasir_T/pen/ZpVbJo . Make sure your page has the jquery.min linked.

Comment: This makes all of them fit inside of the circle which isn't quite what i'm after. If they are bigger than the container i'd like them to use background-size:cover; so they take up the whole space.

Comment: Please check the code pen link http://codepen.io/Nasir_T/pen/ZpVbJo . I have added in jQuery solution. Also editted my answer to show the solution.